# Understanding cout formating in c++

Tags: c++, output, cout

I have been writing in c++ for a while now. When i was working on a project i encountered a solution that might help me but i don't understand how it works. Maybe someone could help me wrap my head around what is going on.

```
for (int i = 1; i < length_of_board - 1; i++) {
  cout << i;
  for (int j = 1; j < length_of_board - 1; j++) {
    cout << (((i > 9) && (j < 2)) ? " " : "  ")
         << ((boardArray[i][j] == '8') ? '.' : boardArray[i][j]);
  }

  cout << endl;
}
```

I what to know what that cout is doing and can i replace it with two if statements.

Comment: Aside: Assuming that `length_of_board` is less than 100, the first could be replaced by having `cout << left << setw(3) << i;` instead of `cout << i;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary operator works like

```
query ? if_true : if_false;
```

In your case this expression is expanded like

```
if((i>9)&&(j<2)) cout<<" "; else cout<<"  ";
if(boardArray[i][j]=='8') cout<<'.'; else cout<<boardArray[i][j];
```

Or for easier reading;

```
if((i>9)&&(j<2))
{
    cout<<" ";
}
else
{
    cout<<"  ";
}
if(boardArray[i][j]=='8')
{
    cout<<'.';
}
else
{
    cout<<boardArray[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ternary` operator can always be replaced with an `if-else` statement. Though the converse is not usually true.

The way a ternary operator works is, the expression before `?` is evaluated, and if it is `true` the expression *before* the `:` is evaluated, otherwise, the expression *after* the `:` is evaluated.

In your example, the equivalent code using `if-else` would look like:

```
if ((i>9)&&(j<2))
  cout << " ";
else 
  cout << "  ";

if (boardArray[i][j]=='8')
  cout << ".";
else
  cout << boardArray[i][j];
```

These are equivalent, and which one you choose depends on which one you find more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it get's a bit clearer when you unwrap

```
cout<<(((i>9)&&(j<2))?" ":"  ")<<((boardArray[i][j]=='8')?'.':boardArray[i][j]);
```

It will become something like this:

```
if(i > 9 && j < 2) {
    std::cout << " "; // One space
}
else {
    std::cout << "  "; // Two spaces
}

if(boardArray[i][j] == '8') {
    std::cout << '.';
}
else {
    std::cout << boardArray[i][j];
}
```

The first part (padding the string with one or two spaces) can be replaced by [std::setw()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

The second part is simply printing a `.` whenever an `8` should be printed.

The exact reason for this is unclear.